# Como eliminar o tbody de uma tabela criada via Javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu crio um `table` dinamicamente a partir do resultado de uma consulta no banco.
Porém gostaria de ter um controle para eliminar o `<tbody>` da mesma.

Eu consigo fazer isso usando o comando :

```
  var body = $("#tbSemana").find('tbody').remove();
  $("#tbSemana").append(document.createElement('tbody'));
```

Porém a `table` não tem *id*, como posso fazer essa mesma exclusão sem o *id*?

segue tabela criada:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < ciclos.length; i++) {
                        var atual = ciclos[i];
                        var html = "<table class=\"table\"><thead>" +
                            "<tr>" +
                            "<th>Pts Sem. 1</th>" +
                            "<th>Qualificação Sem. 1</th>" +
                            "<th>Pts Sem. 2</th>" +
                            "<th>Qualificação Sem. 2</th>" +
                            "<th>Pts Sem. 3</th>" +
                            "<th>Qualificação Sem. 3</th>" +
                            "<th>Pts Sem. 4</th>" +
                            "<th>Qualificação Sem. 4</th>" +
                            "</tr>" +
                            "</thead<tbody><tr>";


                        if (semana[0] != null) {
                            if (true) {
                               //html += "<td>" + atual.id + " - " + atual.nome + "</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.totPst1 + "</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.grad1 + "</td>";
                                a += ciclos[i].totPst1;
                            }
                            else {
                                //html += "<td>" + atual.id + " - " + atual.nome + "</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                        }

                        if (semana[1] != null) {
                            if (true) {
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.totPst2 + "</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.grad2 + "</td>";
                                b += ciclos[i].totPst2;
                            }
                            else {
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                        }

                        if (semana[2] != null) {
                            if (true) {
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.totPst3 + "</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.grad3 + "</td>";
                                c += ciclos[i].totPst3;
                            }
                            else {
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                        }

                        if (semana[3] != null) {
                            if (true) {
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.totPst4 + "</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">" + atual.grad4 + "</td>";
                                d += ciclos[i].totPst4;
                            }
                            else {
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                                html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
                            html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
                        }
                        html += "</tr>";
                        //$("#tbgrad").find('tbody').append(html);
                        html += "</tbody></table>";
                    }
```

Comment: Ao invés de `$("#tbSemana")` use `$("table.table")`

Comment: @Sorack ele exclui outra table que eu tenho na página. Eu só coloquei como exemplo o código, pq uso nela. Agora para excluir um table feita via JavaScript não sei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode selecionar a tabela pelo índice usando `:eq(índice)`, onde índice = 0 se refere à primeira tabela, índice = 1 se refere à segunda e assim por diante.

Para isso, você usa o seletor pegando pela classe `.table`:

```
$(".table:eq(índice) tbody").remove();
```

No exemplo abaixo criei uma função que recebe o índice do botão e exclui o `tbody` da respectiva tabela:

```js
function remove(n){
   $(".table:eq("+n+") tbody").remove();
}

ciclos = semana = [1,2,3,4];
for (var i = 0; i < ciclos.length; i++) {
   var atual = ciclos[i];
   var html = "<table class=\"table\"><thead>" +
       "<tr>" +
       "<th>Pts Sem. 1</th>" +
       "<th>Qualificação Sem. 1</th>" +
       "<th>Pts Sem. 2</th>" +
       "<th>Qualificação Sem. 2</th>" +
       "<th>Pts Sem. 3</th>" +
       "<th>Qualificação Sem. 3</th>" +
       "<th>Pts Sem. 4</th>" +
       "<th>Qualificação Sem. 4</th>" +
       "</tr>" +
       "</thead><tbody><tr>";


   if (semana[0] != null) {
       if (true) {
          //html += "<td>" + atual.id + " - " + atual.nome + "</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
       }
       else {
           //html += "<td>" + atual.id + " - " + atual.nome + "</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
       }
   }
   else {
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
   }

   if (semana[1] != null) {
       if (true) {
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
       }
       else {
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
       }
   }
   else {
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
   }

   if (semana[2] != null) {
       if (true) {
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
       }
       else {
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
       }
   }
   else {
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
   }

   if (semana[3] != null) {
       if (true) {
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">1</td>";
       }
       else {
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
           html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
       }
   }
   else {
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">0</td>";
       html += "<td style=\"text-align: center; \">-</td>";
   }
   html += "</tr>";
   //$("#tbgrad").find('tbody').append(html);
   html += "</tbody></table>";
   
   $("body").append(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="remove(0)">Remover tbody 1</button>
<button onclick="remove(1)">Remover tbody 2</button>
<button onclick="remove(2)">Remover tbody 3</button>
<button onclick="remove(3)">Remover tbody 4</button>
```